# The tag [gmock] is frequently misused for [googlemock] / [c++] related questions?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

When searching for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) I currently get [107 hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20gmock).

[gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock)'s tag [wiki info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gmock/info) states (emphasis mine):

> Gmock (Groovy mocking framework) for the **Groovy programming language** "is all about simple syntax and readability of your tests so you spend less time learning the framework and more writing code."

And thus certainly shouldn't be applied along with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

Well, the tag wiki info also mentions

> Inspired by jMock, EasyMock, and Hamcrest, and designed with C++'s specifics in mind, [Google C++ Mocking Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) (or Google Mock for short) is a library for writing and using C++ mock classes. ...

and links to the [googlemock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlemock) tag's original source.

---

IMHO the correct tag for the (most probably intended) mocking framework applied with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) language, and the [googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googletest) tags should be [googlemock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlemock) actually. To cite from their tag info:

> Inspired by jMock, EasyMock, and Hamcrest, and designed with **C++'s specifics in mind**, Google C++ Mocking Framework (or Google Mock for short) is a library for writing and using C++ mock classes.

The [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) tag currently has 37 followers, where the [googlemock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlemock) is currently watched by 54 followers, and re-tagging should improve the adequate attention by the addressed audience and for future research.

The tags aren't going well to be synonyms though. How should we handle these mistagged questions efficiently<sup>1</sup>?

Wouldn't it be better, to rename the [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) tag with [groovy-mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-mock) (and cleanup the existing questions by re-tagging) to prevent users, to mistag their questions?

---

<sup>1)</sup> I'm currently not so motivated to change all of these manually (well, 107 is still an amount you could consider to do so), and especially not needing to do so in future.

Comment: I think all that should be done is to cleanup the gmock tag.  I can't think of anyway to further disambiguate them without making it confusing.  Unless [groovy-mock] would be OK for regular users?

Comment: @JasonMArcher [tag:groovy-mock] seems to be more appropriate for me, to prevent users mistagging their questions.

Comment: Never mind, apparently there is a built in framework named Groovy Mocks (aka MockFor/StubFor)?