# Can we disambiguate [gmock]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Currently, wiki for [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) states:

> Gmock is a mocking framework for Groovy. Google Mock is a mocking framework for C++.

It seems expected to be used for two different frameworks. According to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295805/the-tag-gmock-is-frequently-misused-for-googlemock-c-related-questions), the original meaning of this tag was for Groovy framework, but GoogleMock consumed it whole. At the moment of writing, 9 questions are tagged with [[groovy][gmock]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock+groovy) and 305 question tagged with [[c++][gmock]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock%20c%2b%2b) and [most of the remaining questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock%20-c%2b%2b%20-groovy%20-googletest%20-googlemock) are about C++, even if it is not tagged.

---

My proposed solution would be to:

- Retag existing [groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy) or [grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails) or [grails-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails-2.0) questios with [groovy-mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-mock) (0 questions currently in [groovy-mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-mock))
- Synonimize [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) to [googlemock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlemock) (consistently with [gtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtest) and [googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googletest)) - 0 score in voting currently.
- Remove tag from questions unrelated to Googlemock:
  [How to add matchers in Python unittest.TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51775993)

Comment: If we're going to be creating the tag for it anyway, and the framework is actually called gmock, then maybe [tag:groovy-gmock] instead of [tag:groovy-mock]?

Comment: Exactly, [groovy-gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy-gmock) and [c++-gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-gmock) seem like the most logical answers to me, in other words: `<language>-<library-name>`.

Comment: @LogicalBranch I assume they'd both come up when you start typing `gmock`?

Answer (score 1):

> - Synonimize gmock to googlemock (consistently with gtest and googletest) - 0 score in voting currently.

I did it long time ago. Now I am watching and fixing questions if [gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) is improperly used.